# Reading Type Signature: Type Constructor & Function Precedence

Tags: purescript

**Context**

```
makeAff ∷ ∀ eff a. ((Either Error a → Eff eff Unit) → Eff eff (Canceler eff)) → Aff eff a
```

https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-aff/blob/master/src/Control/Monad/Aff.purs#L365

**Question**

```
Either Error a → Eff eff Unit
```

Should this be read at as...

1. An `Either` of `Error` or `a → Eff eff Unit`
2. A function that takes an `Either Error a` and returns `Eff eff Unit`

?

Does `→` have a certain type infix precedence?

Comment: It is read as the second. Type application has precedence higher than `→`. In Haskell at least, `→` has the lowest precedence. It is also associates to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application (the whitespace) is the highest precedence "operator" in Haskell while `->` is the lowest.